# Octave - round only one coulmn

Tags: octave

Say I use Octave, and I have this matrix:

```
x =
   85.3407    8.1061
   64.4015    9.9184
   81.1601    7.4629
```

I wanted to round all elements on the first row, without rounding the 2nd row. Is there any way I can do that, without looping all matrix rows? In this case I don't 100 percent care if this is rounding up or down. Just want an efficient way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply an operation on only part of an array, then index it on both the left and right hand side. Like so:

```
x(1,:) = round (x(1,:));
```